# Visual Studio 2022's ClickOnce publishing tool says it published successfully but the output folder is empty

Tags: c#, clickonce, visual-studio-2022

So i have a rather complex but not too complex C# windows form application with a few Nuget dll's.

I am finally done with the project so I want to publish the final version to an onsite server. I read that most recommend I use ClickOnce, a built-in publishing tool that will automatically update the user's app should I make any changes.

When I start the publishing process, I follow the following steps:

1. I right-click the project and select the Publish option. This opens the Publish dialogue.
2. I then create a new publishing format.
3. I select the ClickOnce option for Target. Next.
4. I leave the default Publish location at "bin\publish". Next.
5. I set the Install Location to the "From a UNC path or file share" option and supplied a folder on the server. Next.
6. I check the box to allow "Make available Offline" as well as checking "The application will check for updates". The app will update before starting up. The version will automatically increment. Next.
7. For now, I ignore the sign manifest page. Next.
8. I leave everything on the Configuration page on default. Finish.

I then publish the project and no error code is given.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I then go look for the publish file which is supposed to have the setup.exe and everything but the published files is nowhere to be found. The bin/publish/ folder is empty. The folder on the onsite server is also empty.

I'm not sure what is going wrong but it does not publish despite saying that it published successfully.

I walked through the entire process as I typed this and it still does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you running visual studio with administrator permissions?

Comment: @raBinn I tried it with visual studio 2022 as administrator, same results. It was published successfully but it didn't output anything. The designated folder is still empty.

Comment: try to publish to a local directory to drop write permissions.

Comment: @raBinn with administrator mode I set the directory to a local folder. Still nothing. The destination folder is still empty